# Record audio with display off

Tags: screen, audio-recording

I am having this issue with my Android phone: when I turn the display off, the audio becomes jagged. Here is an example of the issue:

http://chymera.eu/debug/audiobug.wav

This has only started happening recently, and checking in with a few other devices, it seems this is not a generic problem. This is all happening on a CAT S41 with Android 8.0.0

Comment: Usually the component that manges the CPU slows down the CPUs when the screen is off (and no call is running) to save battery. An app developer can set various "WAKE LOCKS" to prevent the system from going into power save or sleep mode. There also extra apps available that can manually or automatically enable such wake locks.

Comment: @Robert As far as I can tell, all audio recording apps suffer from this issue. Can you recommend any applications which allow me to set the wake lock? Would this have to be done generally, or can I make it contingent on whether ro not the recordin gapp or the recording functionality is running?

Comment: I neither do audio recording nor use wake lock apps, I only know they exist, therefore I can't get you any advice. Sorry.